# Detect how long a user has been inactive within a Windows 8 Store app or system wide?

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I am trying to detect how long the user has a been inactive within the app or system wide with the Windows 8 Store apps API.

I look into the system trigger User Away however that just tells you when it goes idle. Doesn't let you specify a certain time. I also took a look at Pointer Pressed and try to detect tap or touch events; but this does not work because I am using a webview and unable to capture PointerPressed events through a web view.

Is there any way to detect if a user has been idle for an X amount of time within the app or system wide? Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Could you put an invisible control over the WebView that catches and notes PointerPressed, but doesn't handle the event?

Comment: Hmm, I looked into doing that, but it seems that I am not able to send  virtually click at a certain location on the WebView. So once I capture the pointer, I would need to send it to the webview. I would provide a source, but I am not able to find the page again that discussed this. I'll update this comment if I happen to find that link again.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up detecting key presses and mouse down events with javascript. Inside the LoadCompleted event, I inject javascripts by using AW_WebView.InvokeScript("eval", new string[] { scriptsString });

Key Press Script:

```
window.document.body.onkeydown = function(event){ 
            window.external.notify('key_pressed');              
         };
```

Mouse Down Scripts:

```
document.onmousedown = function documentMouseDown(e){
         window.external.notify('mouse_down');
    }
```

And you can add additional scripts for additional user events.

When a mouse down or key press is detected, window.external.notify("keypress or mouse down") gets executed. This message gets "received" in my WebView_ScriptNotify event. When I receive a message from my WebView, I set a timer. If the timer is already set, it cancels it and starts the timer again. When the timer has finished, some code gets executed.

```
private void SetTimer(int time)
        {
            if (!TimerEnabled)
            {
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                if (DelayTimer != null)
                {
                    DelayTimer.Cancel();
                    DelayTimer = null;
                }

                //the timeout 
                TimeSpan delay = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(time);

                bool completed = false;

                DelayTimer = ThreadPoolTimer.CreateTimer(
                    (source) =>
                    {    
                        // 
                        // Update the UI thread by using the UI core dispatcher.
                        // 
                        Dispatcher.RunAsync(
                                 CoreDispatcherPriority.High,
                                 () =>
                                 {
                                     // 
                                     // UI components can be accessed within this scope.
                                    //THIS CODE GETS EXECUTED WHEN TIMER HAS FINISHED

                                 });

                        completed = true;
                    },
                    delay,
                    (source) =>
                    {
                        // 
                        // TODO: Handle work cancellation/completion.
                        // 


                        // 
                        // Update the UI thread by using the UI core dispatcher.
                        // 
                        Dispatcher.RunAsync(
                            CoreDispatcherPriority.High,
                            () =>
                            {
                                // 
                                // UI components can be accessed within this scope.
                                // 

                                if (completed)
                                {
                                    // Timer completed.
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    // Timer cancelled.
                                }

                            });
                    });
            }
        }
```

Hope this helps someone! I know this is not a perfect method of getting this done, but for the time being this worked for me.